# Match exact string with strstr

Tags: c, string, char, format, full-text-search

Suppose I have the following string:

```
in the interior of the inside is an inner inn
```

and I want to search, say, for the occurences of "in" (how often "in" appears).

In my program, I've used **strstr** to do so, but it returns **false positives**. It will return:

```
- in the interior of the inside is an inner inn
- interior of the inside is an inner inn
- inside is an inner inn
- inner inn
- inn
```

Thus thinking "in" appears 5 times, which is obviously not true.

How should I proceed in order to search **exclusively** for the word "in"?

Comment: Do you want to say that there is only one "in"?

Comment: In this case, yes, there is only one word "in".

But for the string: "in inner inside in is in", there are 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "in the interior of the inside is an inner inn";
    char *t = "in";
    size_t n = strlen( t );

    size_t count = 0;
    char *p = s;

    while ( ( p = strstr( p, t ) ) != NULL )
    {
        char *q = p + n;
        if ( p == s || isblank( ( unsigned char ) *( p - 1 ) ) )
        {
            if ( *q == '\0' || isblank( ( unsigned char ) *q ) ) ++count;
        }
        p = q;
    }

    printf( "There are %zu string \"%s\"\n", count, t );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
There are 1 string "in"
```

You can also add a check for `ispunct` if the source string can contain puctuations.

Comment: I see my answer follows the logic of yours quite a bit.  +1 to the this earlier answer.

Comment: @chux Straightforward approaches look similarly.

Answer (score 3):

Search for " in "; note the spaces. Then consider the edge cases of a sentence starting with "in " and ending with " in".

Comment: What if the words are separated by commas, dots, exclamation marks and so on?

Comment: Well, as I would say, that's a change in spec! This will do for starters. In reality, use a regular expression library.

Answer (score 2):

One more way to do it is:

Use `strtok()` on your whole sentence with space as delimiter.

So now you can check your token against "in"

Comment: Will this work for "xxin"?  `strtok()` works fine for the trailing delimiter, but not so well for the leading delimiter.

Comment: `strtok()` will cause undefined behaviour if it chews up a read-only string like `const char* foo = "i am in trouble"`

Comment: @chux For a given sentence this will work ans also I meant if you want to check for a "in" in your sentence then this will work

Comment: @Bathsheba Let's not make assumptions !! I agree with your point but OP just wanted to know "in" in the given sentence and this can be done easily using `strtok()`

Comment: @giorgim "always strtok modifies the original string" except _maybe_ in the case of the first pass when no delimiter is found.  As the first parameter is not `const`, `strtok()` is free to play with it.  After a bit, I'll take down my half of our comments.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `isdelimiter()` to check the before and after result of `strstr()`.

```
// Adjust as needed.
int isdelimiter(char ch) {
  return (ch == ' ') || (ch == '\0');
}

int MatchAlex(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
  int match = 0;
  const char *h = haystack;
  const char *m;
  size_t len = strlen(needle);
  while ((m = strstr(h, needle)) != NULL) {
    if ((m == haystack || isdelimiter(m[-1])) && isdelimiter(m[len])) {
      // printf("'%s'",m);
      match++;
      h += len;
    } else {
      h++;
    }
  }
  return match;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", 
      MatchAlex("in the interior of the inside is an inner inn xxin", "in"));
  return 0;
}
```